# Java - Adding images in full screen mode (Developing games in java example - Book)

Tags: java, image, swing, fullscreen

I'm trying to follow a book named "Developing games in Java" written by David Brackeen. In chapter 2, there is an example of how to add images to a full screen application. What he does is that he adds a JPG background image, and then 4 PNG images. I tried to do it like I always do, by writing the code by myself looking at the book. It didn't work.

I searched for errors in the code, changed some things, tried different things, but it didn't work. Then I tried to use his own code, that I downloaded from his website. That didn't work either.. I tried to find another way to add an image, and now I've been searching all morning.. I can't seem to figure out a way to implement images in any other way into this class that's written in this book.. My Java programming level just isn't high enough.

I've tried to understand the code written in the book as much as possible, and I think that I understand most of it. I just can't understand why the images aren't showing up. I'd appreciate if someone could help me on the right track. Here's the code for the file where the images load, downloaded from the authors website (I've modified the brackets and some spaces so that it becomes easier to read)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ImageTest extends JFrame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DisplayMode displayMode;

    if (args.length == 3)
    {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(
            Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            Integer.parseInt(args[2]),
            DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    }
    else
    {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    }

    ImageTest test = new ImageTest();
    test.run(displayMode);
}

private static final int FONT_SIZE = 24;
private static final long DEMO_TIME = 10000;

private SimpleScreenManager screen;
private Image bgImage;
private Image opaqueImage;
private Image transparentImage;
private Image translucentImage;
private Image antiAliasedImage;
private boolean imagesLoaded;

public void run(DisplayMode displayMode)
{
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    setForeground(Color.white);
    setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
    imagesLoaded = false;

    screen = new SimpleScreenManager();

    try
    {
        screen.setFullScreen(displayMode, this);
        loadImages();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(DEMO_TIME);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex){}
    }
    finally
    {
        screen.restoreScreen();
    }
}


public void loadImages()
{
    bgImage = loadImage("images/background.jpg");
    opaqueImage = loadImage("images/opaque.png");
    transparentImage = loadImage("images/transparent.png");
    translucentImage = loadImage("images/translucent.png");
    antiAliasedImage = loadImage("images/antialiased.png");
    imagesLoaded = true;
    // signal to AWT to repaint this window
    repaint();
}


private Image loadImage(String fileName)
{
    return new ImageIcon(fileName).getImage();
}


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    // set text anti-aliasing
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }

    // draw images
    if (imagesLoaded)
    {
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        drawImage(g, opaqueImage, 0, 0, "Opaque");
        drawImage(g, transparentImage, 320, 0, "Transparent");
        drawImage(g, translucentImage, 0, 300, "Translucent");
        drawImage(g, antiAliasedImage, 320, 300, "Translucent (Anti-Aliased)");
    }
    else
    {
        g.drawString("Loading Images...", 5, FONT_SIZE);
    }
}


public void drawImage(Graphics g, Image image, int x, int y, String caption)
{
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    g.drawString(caption, x + 5, y + FONT_SIZE + image.getHeight(null));
}

}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a moderator on Java Forums, I figured out that the problem was in the images path. When I added a full path instead of only using "folderName/imageName", it worked. Strange, but it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it ... I don't see anything that makes the JFrame visible.

Want to add "setVisible(true);" before "screen.setFullScreen(displayMode, this);" on line 48?

If that doesn't work - can you confirm you're you using this SimpleScreenManager? http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/games/JavaIntro/SimpleScreenManager.java

Comment: Adding "setVisible(true);" before the "screen.setFullScreen(displayMode, this);" removed the full screen and made it a tiny small window in the upper left corner of the screen, /:  

And yes, that's the one I'm using!  

Thanks for your reply! (: